# Generate ascii documentation from openapi 3.0 with samples

Tags: quarkus, openapi-generator, asciidoc

I'm using quarkus and openapi-generator-maven-plugin to generate ascii documentation from openapi 3.0 yaml file, but I'm not being able to add the example sample code to request/response.
I have the mustache template but I'm not being able to generate or understand how to automatically create the http-request.adoc/http-response.adoc for all api request.

My directory hierarchy

```
scr  
 └── asciidoc
         └── templates  
               └── index.mustache
```

In my pom I have

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-ascii-docs</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <globalProperties>
                    <apiDocs>true</apiDocs>
                    <apiModels>true</apiModels>
                    <apiTests>false</apiTests>
                    <modelTests>false</modelTests>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                </globalProperties>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/target/openapi/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                <output>${project.basedir}/target/ascii/</output>
                <generatorName>asciidoc</generatorName>
                <generateApiDocumentation>true</generateApiDocumentation>
                <generateModelDocumentation>true</generateModelDocumentation>
                <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                <templateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/asciidoc/templates</templateDirectory>
                <configOptions>                     
                    <useIntroduction>true</useIntroduction>
                    <delegatePattern>false</delegatePattern>
                    <useMethodAndPath>false</useMethodAndPath>
                    <prependFormOrBodyParameters>false</prependFormOrBodyParameters>                    
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In the index.mustache I have (copied from openapi-generator [index.mustache](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/asciidoc-documentation/index.mustache))

```
...

===== Responses

.http response codes
[cols="1,3,2"]
|===
| Code | Message | Datatype

{{#responses}}

| {{code}}
| {{message}}
| {{^simpleType}}{{dataType}}[<<{{baseType}}>>]{{/simpleType}} {{#simpleType}}<<{{dataType}}>>{{/simpleType}}

{{/responses}}
|===

{{^skipExamples}}
===== Samples

{{#snippetinclude}}{{path}}/{{httpMethod}}/http-request.adoc{{/snippetinclude}}
{{#snippetinclude}}{{path}}/{{httpMethod}}/http-response.adoc{{/snippetinclude}}

{{#snippetlink}}* wiremock data, {{path}}/{{httpMethod}}/{{httpMethod}}.json{{/snippetlink}}

{{/skipExamples}}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For this you have to put below configuration in your pom.xml                        

 <additionalProperties>
      snippetDir=${project.basedir}\snippet\
      </additionalProperties>
     <configOptions>
     <skipExamples>false</skipExamples>
     <useIntroduction>true</useIntroduction>
     </configOptions>

Then define the snippet Directory as below in your index.mustache

= {{{appName}}}
    :snippetDir: {{snippetDir}}

For a particular controller, create the folder structure like this- controllerPath1\controllerPath2\HTTPMethod and place your http-request.adoc and http-response.adoc in this

Samples for adoc files are-

   

 .Show Http Request   

 [%collapsible]
    ====
 ....
    {
    "items": [
    { "name": "Foo Performance" },
    { "name": "Foo Sport" },
                { "name": "Foo Signature" }
            ]
 

           }
   

      ....
       ====

When you run maven generate-sources, examples will start reflecting.
Reference link for further detail - 
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/5228
```